# C# Increment array values by 1 using 2 threads?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

If you have the following problem to solve, how would you do it?

The goal is to create an array of 1000 integer values, initialized to 0 and then increment all the values using 2 threads, each thread will increment each array value by 1.

I did it with the following code but I'm really not sure my solution is ok...

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var count = 100;
            int[] array = new int[count];
            Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);

            await Task.WhenAll(IncrementArray(array, "Task 1"), IncrementArray(array, "Task 2"));
            Array.ForEach(array, Console.WriteLine);
        }

        static object obj = new object();

        static async Task IncrementArray(int[] array, string taskName)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(taskName);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                lock (obj)
                {
                    array[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this is a good example of what multithreading is not made for

Comment: What errors or bad results are you getting?

Comment: The way data parallelism typically works is to *partition* the array and have each thread work with its own partition. If you used `Parallel.ForEach` to do the job, that's what the method would do

Comment: That's not even running the code in parallel. Each call to `IncrementArray()` is synchronous.

Comment: What is the *actual* question? It doesn't make sense to use two threads to increment array elements like this, the code won't run any faster. Are you asking how to make the array modifications thread safe? Or how to speed up modifying the entire array? Those are different questions

Comment: As @Matthew says, this code isn't running asynchronously. If you put an `await Task.Delay(1);` inside the `IncrementArray` method and made it `async`, you would then start to see errors as `++` is not thread safe.

Comment: @fubo totally agree with you but it's not the question...

Comment: @PlaTyPuS what *is* the question? This code is synchronous. There are no threads or tasks involved. Even if you used Task.Run the question would still be unclear  -you may just need an `Interlocked.Increment` to safely increase items, or completely different code to speed up the operation. In any case `IncrementArray` shouldn't return a task

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the code, I agree for the lock and that IncrementArray should not return a task... but why do you say the code is synchronous? (ok, here it's the same method called to increment but the 2 tasks should be async no? if the first one takes some time to finish, it doesn't block the execution of the second task right?)

Comment: @PlaTyPuS no. `async` and `await` don't make anything run asynchronously. They allow awaiting *already* running asynchronous operations. Adding that `await Task.Delay()` just *delays* things, and then resumes in the original sync context. In a desktop app, that would be the UI thread. It's pointless to use `Task.Delay()` this way to do anything in the background anyway. Just use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @PlaTyPuS the original code executed one method after the other, *synchronously* and returned a completed task . Then `Task.WhenAll()` awaited one those already completed tasks

Comment: @PlaTyPuS you don't need `lock` if you use `Interlocked.Increment(ref array[i])`

Comment: The thing is, no new threads are created. The call to `WhenAll()` must evaluate all its arguments before it's called - and the two `IncrementArray()` arguments are evaluated sequentially. Both calls to `IncrementArray()` must have returned before `WhenAll()` is called, and since they are called sequentially when pushing the arguments on the stack for the `WhenAll()` call, there is no parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not OK.  You have a race condition, i.e. the two threads may try to increment one element simultaneously and then produce incorrect results - an element of the array may remain 1, for example.

See [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8) class, and also [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) keyword.

Comment: What would you suggest OP locks on though?

Comment: In his particular case, I would suggest to use Interlocked.  However, I prefer to have him do some research first, before jumping to the solution.  Or he will not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Interlocked.Increment` that is like `++` but **atomic** to increse the value in one unit, **keeping it thread safe**